# Discover Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

I see this now on my profile page

> Discover Stack Overflow Careers

[image: discover]

I have already “discovered” Careers, I have had a CV on there for over a year.
This thing should go away if you already have a CV. I would like the option to
hide the button even if I do not have a CV.

Comment: Also, for some users disclosing their real name (which linking a Career profile would do) isn't an option. They shouldn't be forever nagged by a bright orange box.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253459/248731

Comment: @AurélienGasser: by setting this completed, do you mean it is now possible to disable the link altogether? Some kind of feedback would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: @AurélienGasser please give feedback as to why you closed this with no action. It has been over 1 month now

Comment: @AurélienGasser Since this is really a feature request that is incomplete, I've retagged this post.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I can't recall on what basis I marked this question as status-completed, it looks like a mistake on my end

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can replace *Discover...* with *Stack Overflow Careers profile*, which will
contain a link to your profile. Click on the *Edit Profile & Settings* tab:

[image: Edit Profile & Settings tab circled]

then scroll down to the *Web presence* section and tick the *Show Careers link
on my profile* checkbox:

[image: Web presence form shown with checkbox for showing the careers profile]

[Source (deleted)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290337)

This is not exactly what I asked for, but does work for my situation, as I was
able to remove a link to my CV in *About me* and use this new button instead.
However I would prefer these three choices:

- Discover Stack Overflow Careers
- Stack Overflow Careers profile
- No button

Currently no button is not an option.